# Word that describes being "patriotic" for something that is not a country?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that is similar to *patriotic* but does not relate to one's country (or state).

For what it's worth, I'm specifically referring to "overly patriotic" in a negative sense, to describe someone who has a overly sentimental/cultural or otherwise less-than-rational attachment or devotion to something and makes it part of their very identity. A common example might be an extremely zealous football fan.

Comment: Blind loyalty .

Comment: or just loyalist

Comment: Can you Post your idea of "patriotic", please? Can you show more and preferably better examples? In my view, "extremely zealous" here, simply means "unreasonable." Suitable terms for football fans might include "zealous" without the "extremely" but your use of "extremely" queers the whole pitch (no pun intended)…

Answer (score 4):

[**chauvinist**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chauvinism)

> **chauvinist**: 2 : person with an undue partiality or attachment to a group or place to which he or she belongs or has belonged.

Consider also [**sectionalist**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sectionalism).

> **sectionalist**: person with excessive or narrow minded concern for local or regional interests as opposed to the interests of the whole.

"*Sports teams develop a sense of [**sectionalism**](http://www.debate.org/opinions/is-sectionalism-in-the-us-more-harmful-than-nationalism) among US citizens.*"

Comment: I thought about it, but I understand that it us used for you own country, is it?

Comment: My caution with "chauvinist" is that in modern English it is most often used in the context of "male chauvinist", and without another modifier to clarify your intent, that is the meaning most people would assume.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Thought it was more used that way back in the 80s. :-)

Comment: @Elian Well, I'm a child of the 80s so maybe it has stuck with me, while someone younger would not have the same association.  But it's a worthy caution even if only a part of your audience would make that interpretation.

Comment: I thought the term Chauvinist specifically applied to nationalism (specifically French nationalism which the British despised) and all other meanings are secondary.

Answer (score 4):

[**partisan**](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=en&q=partisan+meaning)

From Google:

> noun
>   1. a strong supporter of a party, cause, or person.

Also adjective; the abstract noun is partisanship.

This addresses the question in the title and first paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

When talking about ideology, the word **zealot** is commonly used to imply an obsessive (often negative) devotion.

It can be used for sports fanatics, although I wouldn't use it for something like ethnicity or nationality (which is more something you *are* than an idea/ideal you ascribe to).

And of course, the word **fanatic** also works in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call this person a **fanatic** if you are looking for  a derogatory  expression to patriotic.

Answer (score 0):

two words with different gravity and meaning

*zealotry- Fanatical and uncompromising pursuit of religious, political, or other ideals.

*mania - An excessive enthusiasm or desire; obsession

Answer (score 0):

Try jingoistic.  It refers to just this phenomena. From wikipedia, "refers to excessive bias in judging one's own country as superior to others—an extreme type of nationalism."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingoism

Comment: Good example, and can be applied to many things other than national patriotism -- you can be jingoistic about the company where you work or the sports team you support, and written material/mass media can be jingoistic as well as an individual.  When describing a person, I feel it in particular implies that the person is quite vocal about his or her support, with a tendency to repeat slogans and stock phrases -- but that usually goes along with the description of a "less-than-rational attachment or devotion".

Answer (score -1):

You mention the word 'fan' - and 'fanatic' has come up in other answers, too - and 'fanboy'/'fangirl' would work well in many contexts. Obviously it wouldn't work everywhere - I can't see it being used with political parties, say. But its usage is quite broad - and ever broadening. It works well, obviously, for things like comics, technology, video games and other stereotypically 'geeky' subjects. Things which have cult followings are good, too. But it's also being increasingly used for fanatical interest in bands, TV series, book series and so on.

'Fanboy'/'fangirl' is, in my experience, almost exclusively used negatively by people who aren't fans of the thing in question. It is used to imply that a person's interest in the subject/product/series/etc. is excessive and unreasonable, and also that their opinions (and particularly defences) of it are ludicrously unobjective and disconnected from reality. It also implies that the person is likely to be difficult to argue with on the subject. However, it may be worn as a badge of honour - and taken up with pride - by the fan themselves.