# Patriotic, but for a company?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

If you walk around the US in clothes emblazoned with the American flag, your clothing is **patriotic**.

What is the equivalent when you're wearing company-branded apparel?  Say, Microsoft T-shirts, jacket, cap, etc.

> The cloud computing conference was full of geeks, all dressed head to toe in *X* clothing.

**Corporate** doesn't work, because that implies a generic buttoned-down suit & tie look, not visible devotion to a particular company.  [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166642/word-that-describes-being-patriotic-for-something-that-is-not-a-country) is along the same lines, but is specifically looking for a negative word and remains unaccepted.

Comment: Businesstriotic? Corp-triotic?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to separate this and the linked question, even if the other requests specifically negative and has no accepted answer. Also, the answers here seem to overlap quite a bit with those others. That said, none here or there sound right to me.

Comment: If you were to describe a person who is 'patriotic' to their company, then 'loyal' may suffice, and the meaning is quite clear. However, if you are describing clothing it may be more appropriate to simply describe what is being worn, and allow the reader to make the inference that the person in question is loyal to their company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you walk around the US in clothes emblazoned with the American flag, your clothing is **patriotic**.

Athletes are sponsored by clothing companies to promote them.

Therefore, I would say that if you walk around the US wearing company-branded apparel, your clothing is [**promotional**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promotional):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : the act of furthering the growth or development of something; especially : the furtherance of the acceptance and sale of merchandise through advertising, publicity, or discounting

Comment: Items with company names, slogans, or logos are indeed called promotional items or promotional products (it's a whole industry!) so _...dressed head to toe in **promotional** clothing_ would work, although there could be the connotation of being compensated for wearing such clothing, other than having gotten a free shirt.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn i don't know about that. I promote such companies just by wearing their clothing and not asking for any renumeration. Of course, people who *are* paid promote actively.

Comment: I don't necessarily think **promotional clothing** _implies_ getting paid but some folks might read it that way.   Either way, still a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your own question when you said "company-branded apparel".

> The cloud computing conference was full of geeks, all dressed head to toe in **branded** clothing.

Of course, you could interpret 'branded' to mean any brand, like Nike or Polo or Brooks Brothers, but from the context it should be pretty clear that it refers to Google, Amazon, IBM, etc.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but without the "company-" qualifier, the word implies that they're all dressed up in Gucci or Versace (even though that would admittedly be unlikely at an IT conference!).  It also lacks the nuance of "patriotic" in that the wearer is *proud* to display their affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

If your own *corporate-branded* is not specific enough, you could go with some variation on the corporate equivalent of *patriotism*: ***company spirit***. From *Building company spirit in multidivisional organizations* by Susan Jane Goldsmith Herman, "Company spirit" is

> pride in one's company, a common sense of purpose, pleasure and positive challenge in the work of the organization, security in the work environment, and the feeling of reciprocal support between members and the management of the organization

It's not the smoothest phrase, but it does show up a lot in relation to branded-clothing (especially in the custom-branding industry). For example:

> Start rewarding people for showing **‘company spirit’** by taking on the brand personality and consider new uniforms that make everyone feel like part of the ‘new’ branded team.
>   —["Why A Coherent Brand (From Top To Bottom) Matters", MindShape.com](https://www.mindshape.com/why-a-coherent-brand-from-top-to-bottom-matters/)
>
> • More than 44 percent wear [company-branded apparel] often to show **company spirit**
>   —["New Survey Shows Employees Proudly Wearing Company-Branded Apparel: While Logo-Emblazed Clothing Used to Languish in Closets, Workers Now Say They are Proud to Have Their Jobs", *Bulldog Reporter*, June 24, 2010](https://www.bulldogreporter.com/new-survey-shows-employees-proudly-wearing-company-branded-apparel-while-logo-embla/)
>
> Team Outfitters has a variety of custom packages for school and **company spirit wear**. Our packages range from shirts, fleece, pants and hats to promotional items.
>   —[TeamOutfitters.net](http://www.teamoutfitters.net/index.php/pages/spirit_wear.html)

So in your context, you could say

> The cloud computing conference was full of geeks, all dressed head to toe in **company spirit** clothing.

I might replace "clothing" here with "gear" or "wear" (as in the last quote above), especially if you want to include things like branded [lanyards](http://www.adalternatives.com/lanyard.htm) and [sunglasses](https://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/sunglasses/spirit-sunglasses.htm) that aren't exactly "clothing".

Answer (score -1):

I have heard the word ***fanboy*** used as an adjective, although the Oxford Dictionaries lists it as a noun and a verb:

> ***[fanboy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fanboy)***
>
> **NOUN
>
> *informal*
>
> A male fan, especially one who is obsessive about comics, music, movies, or science fiction.
>
> **VERB**
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> *informal*
>
> (of a male fan) behave in an obsessive or overexcited way.
>
> *‘he fanboyed out meeting his idol on the red carpet’*

Merriam-Webster expands the definition (which matches my experience with the term) and includes an example of *a TED Talk fanboy*:

> Definition of ***[fanboy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fanboy)***
>
> : a boy or man who is an extremely or overly enthusiastic fan of someone or something
>
> *And while her husband might be a TED Talk **fanboy** and just plain obsessed with working in tech, Bernadette has plenty of her own quirks (some great, others…not so great) to discover as well.*

So, in your example, it would be:

> The cloud computing conference was full of geeks, all dressed head to toe in ***fanboy*** clothing.